# Dialog box differs on different browsers version (IE7 and IE9) for same application

Tags: qtp

Dialog box differs on different browsers version (IE7 and IE9) for same application. Please suggest me how to handle this issue. As I need to run the script in different browser version. It’s hard to use separate script for different browser version.

IE7 browser – Browser("xxxxx").Dialog("Windows Internet Explorer").WinButton("OK").Click
IE9 browser – Browser("XXXXX").Dialog("Message from webpage").WinButton("OK").Click

visitjaga@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use descriptive programming and regular expressions to accomplish this.

The example below assumes the object identification property that is dynamic is the "text". Replace this attribute if this is not the correct identification property. Note that you must use descriptive programming for remaining chained objects (lower in the object hierarchy) as well.

```
Browser("xxxxx").Dialog("text:=(Windows Internet Explorer|Message from webpage)").WinButton("text:=OK").Click
```

You can also take the approach of modifying the test object identification property to utilize another property that is static between the two browsers. Use the QTP object spy to compare the properties between the two browsers.